# Select se a coleção contém determinado objeto com Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou tentando fazer uma *query* que seria algo parecido com o método *contains* da *interface* `Collection` do Java.

Tenho uma classe `GrupoProdutos` e quero selecionar os grupos se sua `Collection`, chamada `produtoCollection`, contém um determinado produto de uma outra lista de produtos passada como parâmetro.

Eu tentei assim e não deu certo:

```
session.createCriteria(Grupo.class)
    .createAlias("produtoCollection", "produto")
    .add(Restrictions.in("produto", listaProdutos)).list();
```

Comment: O produto é um item da  collection ou um atributo de um item?

Comment: Pelo o que entendi, você quer saber se produtoCollection (é uma  collection certo?) contém algum item de uma lista passada como parametro?

Comment: Olá Dener, é isso mesmo, quero saber se produtoCollection contém algum produto da listaProdutos que foi passada como parâmetro.

Answer (score 2):

@Resende experimente sobrescrever o equals do "produto". Ou você pode usar a chave primaria dentro da Restricions.in assim:

```
session.createCriteria(Grupo.class)
          .createAlias("produtoCollection", "produtos")
          .add(Restrictions.in("produtos.id", "lista"));
```

Comment: Na o @BrunoCésar editou a minha pegunta, provavelmente deve ser um moderador. Tentei usar a sua dica mais não funcionou deu o seguinte erro: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Comment: Mal, falha minha. Arrumando aqui. O que o erro diz exatamente? Poderia mostrar as classes envolvidas na pesquisa?

Comment: Consegui uma solução usando um foreach, postei em uma resposta separada, não sei se é a melhor forma, mas no momento atendeu a necessidade. Obrigado pelo disponibilidade em ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui uma soluçao usando um loop, não sei se é a melhor solução, mas no momento atendeu a necessidade:

```
     List<Produto> resultList = new arrayList<Produto>();

     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Produto.class)
                    .createAlias("produtoCollection", "produto");
     Disjunction ou = Restrictions.disjunction();
     for(Produto p : listaProdutos){
      ou.add(Restrictions.eq("produto.id", p.getId()));
     }

     resultList = criteria.add(ou).list();
```

Espero que possa ajudar outros com dúvidas semelhantes.

Comment: Já tive um problema parecido, que resolvi a partir da resposta que te dei ali. De qualquer forma você pode dar uma olhada nesse artigo aqui http://blog.caelum.com.br/divisions-com-hibernate-uso-avancado-da-criteria-api/ creio que pode te ajudar

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, o artigo da caelum foi relamente muito útil. Valeu mesmo.